# Editing wsdl file

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, websphere

I have just created a Java Web Service (JAX-RPC) with the bottom-up method and now I want to modify the wsdl auto-generated so I can add some restrictions to some elements.

For example, instead of this:

```
<element name="code" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
```

I have this:

```
 <element name="code" nillable="true">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:length value="14"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
 </element>
```

to restrict the length of this field.

I republish The server and it seems that this change is not taking in account. Im testing with a simple client passing a "code" of length 8, and it seems to ignore the restriction I add in the WSDL.

Is there something I'm missing? I need to do something special to add that kind of restrictions? may I have to regenerate the webservice starting with the WSDL modified using the top-down method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will definitely need to re-generate the WSDL for this change to take effect.

Comment: The thing is that if I access the WSDL publicated in the server through "URL"?WSDL I can see the WSDL with that modification. But still don't work the restriction... May be is time to learn how to build the webservice with the wsdl as starting point. Thanks for reply JamesB.

Comment: What application server are you using?

Comment: I'm Using WebSphere AST 6.1. Sorry, I miss to say it.

Comment: And you generate the WSDL from your XSD schema? Which tool are you using for that?

Comment: I generate the webservice with the wizard using a JavaBean. So the wsdl is auto-generated. then, what I want is to modify that wsdl to add restrictions to some fields.

Comment: So you modify the WSDL by hand after it has been generated?

Comment: That's right, I just substitute the code as I say above.